# Maple Help format output collect terms with same coefficients and multiple variables

Tags: maple

I realize this may have been asked before, however I have no idea what to search for specifically, since the topic is so generic it returns so many results that I cannot find what I am looking for.

eqn3:=3.9024*x+3.9024*y;

How can I get Maple to output as (3.9024)(x+y) instead of (3.9024)(x)+(3.9024)(y)?

I have tried factor, collect, simplify, etc.  I am using Maple 16

Comment: Having no experience in Maple, all I can guess is that 3.9024 is a float and therefore it may not be equal to itself.

Answer (score 2):

Note that automatic simplification distributes numeric coefficients, e.g.
if you enter

```
> expr:= 3.9024*(x+y);
```

the result will be

$$ expr := 3.9024 x + 3.9024 y $$

To defeat this, one way is to use the `` function.

```
> E:= map(t -> (t = ``(t)), indets(expr,float)):
> collect(subs(E, expr),``);
```

$$ (x + y) (3.9024) $$

Unfortunately I don't see how to put the $(3.9024)$ before the $(x+y)$.
It thought it would be possible with **sort**, but I can't seem to find the right options.  Well, here's a rather kludgy work-around.

```
> restart;
  expr:= 3.9024*(x+y);
  E:= map(t -> t = ``(t), indets(expr,float));
  subs(x=w-y,E,expr);
  sort(%,w);
  subs(w=x+y,%);
```

$$ (3.9024)(x+y) $$